# Snowflake stream behavior

Tags: stream, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have following fields in table 1-
db,schema,jobnm,status,runtime, ins_tstmp, upd_tstmp.

A stream has been created on table 1.

A stored procedure was written to loop through another table's dataset (4 records) and write all 4 records to table 1 if they don't already exist else update (using merge sql here; ins_tstmp gets populated via insert part of merge while upd_tstmp gets updated via update part ).

As expected, table1 has all 4 records and Stream also has 4 records with metadata$action as INSERT . UPD_TSTMP is null here.

Now on 2nd run, same 4 records were retrieved. Since they were a match, upd_tstmp got populated in both table 1 and stream but why metadata$action is INSERT only? Not seeing 2 entries for an update. Could someone please explain what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you didn't consume the stream between the first and second run. As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html), a stream will show the delta change (difference between the starting point and the ending point) which in your case are all INSERT because the starting point was an empty table and the ending point are records in the table, regardless of changes (updates) that happen in between. If you consume the stream between the first run and the second run, you will then see updates in the stream.

Comment: @MajaF., Thanks for the input. I added a second table and consumed stream data into it. This is all happening as part of stored procedure. On first and second runs, it is still the same behavior. I don't see INSERT/DELETE for an UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

> Since they were a match, upd_tstmp got populated in both table 1 and
> stream but why metadata$action is INSERT only?

The METADATA$ACTION column can have 2 possible values: INSERT and DELETE. So you can't see "UPDATE" in this column.

METADATA$ISUPDATE: This is an extra column indicating whether the operation was part of an UPDATE statement. In your case, you should also see it "false" because Streams record the differences between two offsets. If a row is added and then updated in the current offset, the delta change is a new row. The METADATA$ISUPDATE row records a FALSE value.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro.html#stream-columns

Comment: DELETE row isn't showing up in the Stream. I see only an INSERT row and METDATA@ISUPDATE is FALSE

Comment: Thanks for the doc reference here. I think what's happening is, I am processing the same row with no actual value change to any of the fields. Even though update section is executing as part of the merge, stream isn't capturing that as a real update. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user19184678 even if your update is a real update (changing a column etc), it will still be seen as "INSERT" and "ISUPDATE=false", if it is done after an INSERT. Because the stream is not for logging, it's for capturing the change and providing "delta"